# While dual booting alongside win7 ult

Tags: 14.04, boot, windows-7

When I get the hang of ubuntu, and I like it more than win 7. How would I be able to uninstall win 7 from my computer and just have Ubuntu as the main os? Since my laptop already came with win 7. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Format the partition with Windows (GNOME Disks or GPartEd can do that for you), then `sudo update-grub` so Grub knows Windows isn't there anymore.